# Why "motherboard" is used to refer to main board of computer

Tags: etymology, terminology, technical, computing

Why is *motherboard* used to refer to the main board of a computer? What is the relationship with the word *mother* here?

Answer (score 20):

It's called a motherboard because it is the main circuit board in the computer, and it can be extended by plugging other circuit boards into it. These extensions are called daughter boards. [Wikipedia suggests that historically a "mainboard" was not extensible in this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard), hence the need for different terminology. Many computer terms use human or biological words as metaphors:

- Master/Slave (controller and devices)
- Male/Female (plugs and ports)
- Mouse
- Peers
- Server/Client

Comment: +1 The mother-daughter relationship is clear, but why feminine, I don't know. Elsewhere in computing, we talk of parent-child relationships, so why not with the main board in a computer? In my experience, it has simply 'always been the case'...

Comment: I'd guess that it's "Mother/daughter" for the same reason that it's "Motherland", "Mother-ship", etc. It sounds foreign to me to talk of the "Fatherland", etc.

Comment: re Male / Female: http://message.snopes.com/showpost.php?p=464706

Comment: @CJM, maybe it's an umbilical metaphor?

Comment: The relationship -- the child board clings to it, drawing sustenance, protection, and support -- seems maternal to me.  Of course, maybe that just says something about my relationship with my parents...

Comment: @CJM Why feminine? Well, the term used before daughter-board was [baby-board](@JasperLoy Why mother-board? Before daughter-board came [baby-board](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/why-motherboard-is-used-to-refer-to-main-board-of-computer/48013#48013). This at least explains why *mother-* and not *father-*.

Comment: The term "daughter card" is also used (possibly more than daughter board), likely to emphasize the fact that the daughter *card* plugs into the mother *board*, and also because the former tend to be smaller.

Answer (score 13):

## Mother-board

> In personal computers, a [motherboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard) is the central printed circuit board (PCB) in many modern computers and holds many of the crucial components of the system, providing connectors for other peripherals.

The first references I found are in [1956](https://www.google.com/search?q=motherboard&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=motherboard+OR+mother-board+OR+%22mother+board%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XnK6TpmjI6jc0QGJ-fjfCQ&ved=0CBwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1956%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1956&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3a82ac68bcbcfab4&biw=1920&bih=1057) to *"mother" board*, *"mother-board"* and *"mother board"*; the quotes suggest this is new terminology.

- EIA's [1956](http://books.google.com/books?id=OF4UAQAAMAAJ&q=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&dq=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&hl=en&ei=_fi8TqqpFYrE8gPC6uWPBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBg) *Proceedings*:

[image: The units incorporate all of the sub -module features which we previously described, but here the repetitive components are mounted on what might be termed a "mother" board.]

- IRE's [1956](http://books.google.com/books?id=3lFVAAAAYAAJ&q=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&dq=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&hl=en&ei=_fi8TqqpFYrE8gPC6uWPBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBQ) *International Convention Record*, Volume 4, Part 2:

[image: Fig. 12 is an illustration of the so-called "baby-board" to "mother-board" package where the tube sub-modules are mounted on the larger board and the circuit sub-modules on the right angle small boards. The arrangement can be easily reversed.]

- Ziff-Davis's [1956](http://books.google.com/books?id=1BlKAQAAIAAJ&q=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&dq=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&hl=en&ei=_fi8TqqpFYrE8gPC6uWPBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBA) *Popular Electronics*, Volume 4, Issues 1-6:

[image: was mounted on a large "mother board." Two other boards were used: one was for the power supply, and the other was for the readout subassembly.]

- Hayden's [1956](http://books.google.com/books?id=7XFJAQAAIAAJ&q=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&dq=motherboard%20OR%20mother-board%20OR%20%22mother%20board%22&hl=en&ei=_fi8TqqpFYrE8gPC6uWPBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw) *Electronic Design*, Volume 4, Part 2:

[image: A variant is the i-f strip, below, where repetitive components are mounted on "mother" board.]

---

## Baby-board

The observant will have noticed one of these early uses of *mother-board* are in conjunction with *baby-board*, and not today's common *daughterboard*. A mother-baby relationship seems more appropriate in this context than mother-daughter.

---

## Daughter-board

> A [daughterboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughterboard), daughtercard or piggyback board is a circuit board meant to be an extension or "daughter" of a motherboard (or 'mainboard'), or occasionally of another card.

*Daughterboard* is the most common term nowadays. When did this replace *baby-board*?

The earliest I found was ten years later, in [1965](https://www.google.com/search?q=motherboard&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=daughterboard+OR+daughter-board+OR+%22daughter+board%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bnO6Tq-7Aci20QH3jtnfCQ&ved=0CBwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1965%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1965&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3a82ac68bcbcfab4&biw=1920&bih=1057) as *daughter board*, *"motherboard-daughter board"* and *mother-daughter board*.

- Hayden's [1965](http://books.google.com/books?ei=7AO9To_fCYWc8gOGqcmbBA&ct=result&id=O3ZJAQAAIAAJ&dq=daughterboard%20OR%20daughter-board%20OR%20%22daughter%20board%22&q=daughter-board#search_anchor) *Electronic Design*, Volume 13, Part 3

[image: The daughter board can not be removed without using the tool again. (Keeping a spare tool on hand is wise with this approach. ... The number of microcircuits to put on each daughter board was a difficult design decision. ...]

- Rogers' [1965](http://books.google.com/books?id=cgNTAAAAMAAJ&q=daughterboard%20OR%20daughter-board%20OR%20%22daughter%20board%22&dq=daughterboard%20OR%20daughter-board%20OR%20%22daughter%20board%22&hl=en&ei=7AO9To_fCYWc8gOGqcmbBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ) *Advances in Electronic Circuit Packaging*:

[image: Some special pins for attachment to the edge of a printed circuit board (currently available for 0.031" thick boards only), allow the plug-in connection at right angles, in "motherboard-daughter board" fashion.]

- McGraw-Hill's [1965](http://books.google.com/books?id=_xpRAAAAYAAJ&q=daughterboard%20OR%20daughter-board%20OR%20%22daughter%20board%22&dq=daughterboard%20OR%20daughter-board%20OR%20%22daughter%20board%22&hl=en&ei=7AO9To_fCYWc8gOGqcmbBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA) *Electronics*, Volume 38:

[image: There are flatpacks, micromodules, film structures, mother-daughter board combinations and matrix configurations that defy description. And the only thing standard about them is that they're all different.]

Answer (score 6):

*Mother lode* and *mother ship* are older compounds along similar lines (both dating to at least 19th century, in mining and whaling respectively).  Perhaps *motherboard* was coined by analogy with one of those?  (Influence from *mother ship* seems very plausible, due to its sci-fi popularity.)

In each case, “mother X” seems to mean roughly “a big X, associated to some group of smaller X’s” — the metaphor seems fairly clear.

Unfortunately I can’t find any reliable sources right now with specific info on the origin of *motherboard* — hopefully someone else can, or I’ll try again tomorrow when I have OED access again…

Comment: In the case of *mother ship*, I presume it’s because ships were traditionally personified as female.  In the case of *mother lode*, Wikipedia says it’s a translation from the Spanish *vita madre*; but that still leaves the question of why the Spanish phrase in turn used *mother*…

Comment: *Veta*, actually. Maybe they used *madre* with it because *veta* is grammatically feminine in Spanish?

Comment: Computers frequently also (used to) have *daughter-boards*. Just throwing this in here...

Comment: Daughter boards plug into mother boards.

Comment: @JasperLoy Why mother-board? Before daughter-board came [baby-board](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/why-motherboard-is-used-to-refer-to-main-board-of-computer/48013#48013).